# Not able to import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;

Tags: android

I have installed Google Play Services and have imported the library into the project. This is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    }
```

The third line is where google play services library is imported. But when I try to import `com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient` I get an error. what is the solution? Thanks:D

Comment: public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps to import the library and add to the dependencies

1. Drag and Drop the file into your lib folder
2. Right Click on the project
3. Select OpenModule Setting
4. Go to dependencies Tab
5. Click the + button file dependencies and add the library of GMS which you have drag and drop

Hope You were clear!!!

Comment: thanks a lot u mean I have to open the lib folder and paste the library file there?

Comment: I am not able to find googleplayservices.jar library file. Please help. this is urgent.

Comment: wow thanks but it will be great if u can email me an working template or project at vipulbansalkkp@gmail.com

Comment: hey man! follow this tutorial it also working copy I have tested. Do not forgot to mark as my method is correct.

Comment: pls gimme ur email or Skype id

Comment: you can carry on this chat

Comment: have you try the tutorial I have send

Comment: follow this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/ with patient

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're importing right class?

I've been adding this library also the way you did and that works Ok. You also need to add meta-data in `Manifest`:

```
<application>
...
    <!--
        Required for Google Maps
     -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="ANDROID_MAPS_API_KEY_GOES_HERE" />
...
```

Try import this one:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
```

Comment: I have tried but nothing is working. Can I know ur email. I will send u the project.

Comment: upload it to dropbox or Google Drive and give me a link.

Comment: this is my code:   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{

Comment: I will email u I don't have a google drive account. Pls gimme ur email

Comment: Okay, send here: AnZyuZya@i.ua

Comment: may I know ur Skype id. mine is vipulbansal86

Comment: i could only sent main file as i could not send whole project due to gmail issue

Comment: have u received email

Comment: Stop tilting. No need to spam. Just add to .zip file your project and send it

Comment: i added project to zip file but gmail doesn't permit to send due to security issues pls look at the main activity file please

Comment: i have sent the main activity file

Comment: code seems okay. I need the entire project to import it. Try upload it as zip to ge.tt or some other hosting

Comment: change `GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and `GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` to  `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` respectively where your `implements` is.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Module -->`Open Module Settings` --> Select `Dependencies` tab --> Click on `add(+)` button --> Select `Library dependency` --> Now from list select `Play service` --> Click `Apply` --> Clock `Ok`

**Update**

Actually there is `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` interface but not `GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`. For reference check the link [developers.google.com/games/services/android/init](http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init)

Comment: I did it but its to no usw

Comment: this is my code:   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{

Comment: @vipulbansal once check your code properly actually there is GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener interface but not GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener. For reference check the link https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

Comment: this is the right one. Please send me a working project

Comment: Sorry @vipulbansal I didn't worked on it...From above link you can get some guidance  how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

use:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
in gradle file